# Opengeocode.org account has been suspended?

Tags: internet, geocoding

Does anyone know what has happened to 
[opengeocode.org](http://opengeocode.org)

The well used website is showing that the account has been suspended

[image]

Comment: Makes sense to contact http://stackoverflow.com/users/622104/andrew-opengeocode

Comment: You may have luck with internet archive until an answer is found `https://web.archive.org/web/*/opengeocode.org` or specifically this snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20160305091247/http://opengeocode.org/

Comment: The internet archive is useful thanks. Andrew-opengeocode's profile says he hasn't been on for nearly 2 months

Answer (score 1):

Suspensions usually occur for reasons such as non-payment, or possibly violations of terms of use. In any event, it's not likely to be a good thing, unless it was done in error.